# How to forbid the closing of sp notification?

Tags: 2013, javascript, form, status, sp.ui

When I want to add a simple SharePoint notification to my page, I can do the following:

```
 SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Some process is running...", true);
```

[image]

But when I click on this notification it just closes, even if the process is not finished.
Is there any way to forbid its closing on click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SP.UI.Notify.addNotification` return id of the newly created notification (DOM element).  It also attaches click handler on child `div` element, what you can do is unbind click event by replacing child div with copy:

pure js:

```
var notifId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Some process is running...", true);
var old_element = document.querySelector("#" + notifId + " > div");
var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);
old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);
```

or with jquery:

```
var notifId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Some process is running...", true);
jQuery("#" + notifId + " > div").replaceWith(jQuery("#" + notifId + " > div").clone());
```